# Problem in adding different 'data' 'value' variable in echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

Here's the link to my example https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=sunburst-visualMap

The data has keys such as name, value and children.
I want the above example to plot the map using 'score' instead of 'value' in the visual Map.

I tried using a formatter function inside the 'label' which isn't working.

`formatter: function (param) { console.log(param);  return param.data.score; }`

Comment: I dont think there is out of the box support. You can set [itemStyle](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-sunburst.data.itemStyle) inside data and compute your preferred color while building the data object.